# Карточка пользователя под каждую роль. Как лучше?

Tags: база-данных

В системе есть пользователь. У него есть некие поля (видно на скрине). Эти поля общие для всех пользователей в системе. У этого пользователя может быть N-е кол-во ролей. У каждой роли есть специфичные поля, которые должны быть заполнены по каждому пользователю, если у него есть эта роль.

Как лучше изобразить это в БД?

У меня получилось что-то такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ИМХО, можно `UserRoleFiledValue` таблицу связать не с `user`+`role`, а с `userRole`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб чем это лучше?

Comment: Например тем, что в UserRoleFiledValue  будет на одну колонку меньше